# Setting up and configuring Faker Js for CodeceptJs

Tags: codeceptjs, faker.js

really having trouble with setting up and configuring faker to work on codeceptjs, I have had a look at their website but no luck with the set up.

I just need need a simple example of faker within a test case.

I have installed through npm 'rosie' and 'faker', but there was no mention if i need to add anything to the cocept config file

I am just trying to generate a random 'first name' and 'last name for a website that I am testing, but as said earlier stuck on this.

Example of the the test

```
var Factory = require('rosie').Factory;
var faker = require('faker');

module.exports = new Factory()

   .attr('first name', () => faker.first.name.findName());


Feature('checkout');

Scenario('test something', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage(''),
    I.wait(5);
    I.moveCursorTo('//a[contains(text(),"Products")]');
    I.wait(1);
    I.moveCursorTo('//a[contains(text(),"Patient Care")]');
    I.wait(1);
    I.click('//a[contains(text(),"Patient Protectors")]');
    //I.wait(2);
    I.click('//img[@alt="Blue Disposable Bibs"]');
    //I.wait(2);
    I.click('Add to basket')
    //I.wait(5);
    I.click({css:'i.fa.fa-shopping-basket'});
    I.wait(5);
    I.click('//a[contains(@href, "")]');
    I.fillField('First Name', faker.first.name());
    I.wait(5); //check to see if this worked
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The faker library that will generate a first name is under "name". You currently have `faker.first.name.findName()`. See Codecept.js with `faker` example below:

```js
    var faker = require('faker');
    
    Feature('Test using faker');
    
    Scenario('Verify that a user is able to add first name to first name field',({ I }) => {
        patientfname = faker.name.firstName()
        I.click('#firstnamefieldid')
        I.fillField('#firstnamefieldid', patientfname)
    });
```